# assebly scanning for specific classes or intefaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

using dependendy injection and others I need often to declare which dependent assembly must be scanned for a specific class or classes the derives from specific classes or classes that implements interfaces and I have to declare in an explicity way the assemblt to load one by one.
  is the any way in asp.net core / dot net core to scan for classes that implements specific class and/or interface?

Comment: yes, reflection.. you should look into that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: Assembly.GetType() overloads will give you a result, if your searched type is in this assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using `IsAssignableFrom` on the interface or base class that you want to check if the class implements/inherits from:

```
bool implementsInterface = typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(classInstance);
bool inheritsBaseClass   = typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(classInstance);
```